# C++ File IO, how to specify output location

Tags: c++, file-io

I've been trying to learn File IO in C++ via tutorial webs and came across the following code.

Now, how do I specify the location of the output file? I've tried running the code and search for the location of the file but didn't work.

Thank you.

```
ofstream myfile ("InOutExample.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    myfile << "This is a line.\n";
    myfile << "This is another line.\n";
    myfile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
return 0;


system("pause");
```

Comment: Just include the path in the name.

Comment: You mean the path?  Specify a *full path* when you open the file.

Comment: Yes, I meant the path. So like "C:\Example.txt" ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: @Androidy - That's the web I got the code from. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the location, it will put it there.

```
ofstream myfile ("c:\\temp\\InOutExample.txt");
```

If you don't put a full path, it puts it in the current working directory.

Comment: Hmm, it wasn't found in my working directory, I"ll try again. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes the current working directory is not what you think it is, especially if you are running this in an IDE, most especially Visual Studio.

Comment: SndLt - do you know where the file is? If so, like I said, just put the full path (making sure to do double \\ instead of single), and it should work.